# ASP.NET MVC - How to correctly 'cache' users ID's?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have a MVC4 web app that calls to a WebApi. The WebApi returns a JSON list of objects that are then converted to a appropiate `Model` and passed to the `View`.

Currently I am 'caching' this list of objects before its passed to the `View` in a `Session` variable that can then be paged through pagination.

I know this is bad. My idea is to store the JSON list in a database.

What I need to do is determine the best way to associate the a JSON item list in the database with the user that requested it. I was thinking of creating a `Session` variable each time a user first accesses the `Controller` of the app and then store the ID (based on a GUID) that can then be queried against the database.

Again the above idea requires the use of a `Session` which is bad. What could I use instead?

Please note I have no Login in system and therefore no 'Users' table so ID's will have to be assigned on the fly.

Comment: Each session has a Session ID...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you keep in session will be available to any request from the current session until session expires.

Session is not always bad. There are some valid use cases where you can store some data in session provided you are not using the In-Memory session. **Using In-Memory session is bad**. You should use a small db table to store the data you wish to keep in session (*Ex : Shopping cart data etc..*) or if you really want session(why?), you should use StateServer  or SqlServer session modes

If you do not wish to keep your app's local db to store this information, You may also consider keeping that in a caching layer instead of session. You may use the `MemoryCache` class available in dot net.

Quick sample of setting data to the cache.

```
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

var products = new List<string> { "iPhone","MacBookPro","Beer"};
var userId=25;
var cacheKey="productsOf"+userId;

cache.Set(cacheKey, products, policy);
```

And to read from the cache,

```
var userId=25;
var cacheKey="productsOf"+userId;
var test= cache.Get(cacheKey);
```

`Get` method returns an object and you need to explicitly cast it to your custom class/data structuer. You can keep any object in the cache. Based on your specific requirement update the expiration date of the cache. `MemoryCache` class is available in the `System.Runtime.Caching` namespace.

Similar to in-memory session, cache will be automatically cleared periodically. So your best bet is to use a small local db table i guess.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. My object I'm currently storing in the Session may have a list of 100+ objects. I'm not seeing any performance issues with this and it allows me to achieve the fast paging I require. Would you consider a list of 100+ objects in a Session ok?

Comment: Depends on what you have in those objects and how light/heavy those are. Remember session is stored in server and you should not overload it. Cache or persist the minimal information needed.